# Installation new domain controller throws error about used ports (88)

Tags: windows, domain, windows-server, ports

When I configure my server as the first Active Directory domain controller in a new forest in Windows Server 2016 I get error as below:

> Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed.
>   The TCP ports required by Active Directory Domain Services are already
>   in use on this computer. You must remove or reconfigure the services
>   that are currently using these ports (88, 389, 636, 3268, 3269).

Only one port from these is in use - 88. I checked in resource monitor app that process named System use it.

What can I do to release this port?

[image: screen from resources monitor]

Comment: "netstat -ab" will list all open ports, and the applications that have those ports in use. "Netstat -aon will list all open ports and the process ID (PID) of the application that has the port open. You would then go to task manager and look up the PID to determine theapplication name and location.

Comment: yes, I check that but as I wrote, the process ID point to **System** process

Answer (score 0):

On the computer hosting your CA, on the Windows desktop, select Start > Programs > Administrative Tools, and then select Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager dialog, Connections pane, expand your computer name, expand Sites, and select Default Web Site.

On the Actions pane, select Bindings.

In the Site Bindings dialog, select specific port option delete the service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).